# Tycho plugin for eclipse product is not creating launcher.ini file

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, packaging, tycho, eclipse-pde

I am in the process of Maven-izing an existing Eclipse plugin product build, using Tycho. Unfortunately, it is not packaging the launcher ini file.

However, this is present when I export the product from Eclipse.

Is there any configuration in the pom or elsewhere that I need to mention something?

**Product File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="Eclipse Product" uid="Product" id="prod-plugin.Product1" application="org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" version="4.0.0" useFeatures="false" includeLaunchers="true">

   <aboutInfo>
      <image path="/prod-plugin/icons/prod128.png"/>
      <text>
         An Eclipse Application
      </text>
   </aboutInfo>

   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <programArgs>-consoleLog-Xss512m
      </programArgs>
      <vmArgs>-Xms1G -Xmx3G -Xss1G -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
      </vmArgs>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages i16="/prod-plugin/icons/prod16.png" i32="/prod-plugin/icons/prod32.png" i48="/prod-plugin/icons/prod48.png" i64="/prod-plugin/icons/prod64.png" i128="/prod-plugin/icons/prod128.png" i256="/prod-plugin/icons/prod256.png"/>

   <splash
      location="prod-plugin"
      startupProgressRect="2,277,655,10"
      startupMessageRect="7,259,590,18"
      startupForegroundColor="FFFFFF" />
   <launcher name="prod">
      <win useIco="false">
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>

   <vm>
      <windows include="true">org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8</windows>
   </vm>

   <plugins>
      <plugin id="prod-plugin"/>
      .....
   </plugins>

   <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.felix.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.felix.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="3" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.felix.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
   </configurations>

   <preferencesInfo>
      <targetfile overwrite="false"/>
   </preferencesInfo>

   <cssInfo>
   </cssInfo>

</product>
```

Comment: No, that should work even POM-less. For 1+2 show your product definition and for 2 also your target definition file.

Comment: `org.eclipse.equinox.event.source` is a source code plugin, it is unusual to need those.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449! Yes, it seems to have been added by a developer. Got rid of that dependency!

Comment: Since the launcher name is specified as `prod` you should be getting a `prod.exe` and a `prod.ini` - is that not happening?

Comment: Nope @greg-449. prod.exe is generated, but not the ini.

Comment: Your `prod.ini` should be generated from what you have in the `<launcherArgs>...</launcherArgs>`. `-consoleLog-Xss512m` looks wired: probably it should be `-consoleLog` in `<programArgs>` and `-Xss512m` belongs into `<vmArgs>`. Maybe there are some invisible special characters in the `<launcherArgs>...</launcherArgs>` section causing `prod.ini` not to be generated.

Comment: @howlger - I realized that ```-Xss512m``` was wrongly appended to the ```programArgs```. I have removed it. I have also taken care that there are no special characters inside the ```launcherArgs```. In fact as I have mentioned in the original question, it is working perfectly well when exported from Eclipse.

Comment: Does it work with Tycho without `<preferencesInfo>...</preferencesInfo>`. What is the reason for `<targetfile overwrite="false"/>` without `path="..."`? Which Tycho, Maven and Java version do you use?

Comment: @howlger - I did this and checked as well. It didn't work. I think that it has something to do with ```pom.xml``` and not the ```product``` file itself, as it works on Eclipse. In ```pom.xml```, in the ```<configuration>``` for ```materialize-products```, what is the value that I need to pass for ```<id>```, is it the name of the ```product``` file, or the ```id``` or ```uid``` mentioned in it? I could be wrong somewhere there.

Comment: In the [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/28854a9ebddf563e5154c95392c9d1de4c2ef385/product/pom.xml#L54) the product ID value is the [product's UID](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/28854a9ebddf563e5154c95392c9d1de4c2ef385/product/idealized.product#L4).

Comment: Thanks @howlger! When we went the pom.xml we realized that we had completed messed up between plugins and plugins-management. We have corrected it, and it works now!

Comment: Good to hear that it works now. You might give a self-answer.